# PHP / MySQL using varchar as a sort of id

Tags: php, mysql

I have to create a database that contains some information about a few products and some SKU's, part of this is the product type and sub-type, having a total of 60-70 product types and 2-20 sub-types for each of them.

The part of SKU code that needs to be generated is in the form XXY, where XX is the product type and Y is the sub-type of it, for the type part it was easy to add a unique auto_increment field (since it will never go over 99) but for the sub-type part i need to use both numbers and letters in an order like 1-9-A-Z.

What is the simplest way to achieve this ? I have some idea how to do it with javascript / json to check and retrieve the Y field but i got a feeling there must be an easier way with just using php/mysql for this.

Basically what i need is for php/mysql to generate a single-character "id subtype" from 1 to Z for each unique product type.

Comment: You can try to create a poor man's auto increment with a before insert trigger, but with chars you will not be able to get the new value in your php script unless you select the row after inserting it. It will probably be best to use PHP to generate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to use Javascript or PHP (or anything you are using server side) to generate this char. There's no builtin SQL function to do that. For your single-character id subtype you shouldn't use `VARCHAR` BUT `CHAR(1)`.

`CHAR` has a fixed length, therefore will take only 1 byte per character. `VARCHAR` takes the same as `CHAR` + 2 bytes to hold length information.

Example:

```
$characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'; 
$char = strtoupper($characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)]);
```

Comment: He could use this sign as a 1-byte unsigned INT that would hold ASCII code, and set a trigger ON INSERT if it is beyond 1-9 and beyond A-Z it should be changed. But I'm not sure if this is "the simplest way".

Comment: @Jueecy Can this be done only in php ? Since when the user sees the form for the first time i don't know what type will be selected, i guess i need to use some javascript to check the database after the select field with type is selected and see where subtype id is at and then add to it.

Comment: @Voitcus do you have any example for this ? Meanwhile I'm looking through the mysql docs.

Comment: @Adrian I don't have any examples, but it would be something like `CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT ON table_name FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF NEW.column_with_char_ascii (outside a specific range of ascii code) THEN SET NEW.column_with_char_ascii = (another char) END IF END`

Comment: @Adrian, I'm assuming that the entering (inserting) of the product is done by PHP therefore creating a single char is very simple. Edited with a PHP example. Also I'd suggest you to use only PHP since Javascript can be easily forged and modified by the user.

Comment: Managed to do it in php by counting the rows and adding A-Z if it's bigger then 9, thank you for your time.